# How to get the document icons for a QLPreviewItem?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, quicklook

Is it possible to get the icon for a QLPreviewItem in iOS? I imagine this similar to what Mail.app shows for attachments. Just a simple icon representing the file type of the object in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `UIDocumentInteractionController`:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSArray *icons
```